# PHP / MySQL Simple IF / ELSE not so simple

Tags: php, mysql

I think my mind must be going through a Boxing Day mess.

I am building a basic comment section for every game a sports team plays.

So, when no comments are entered (in the MySQL DB), I simply want to display "Be the first to enter a comment"; otherwise, display the comment results table in html format.

I can easily display the comment result table.

For some reason, I can't get the IF no comments to work properly.  Feel so amateurish right now . . . :-)

I have declared row count:

```
 $row_count = 0;
```

I am adding to the count inside the while statement

```
     while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
     {
          // adding to count
          $row_count++;
```

My count is working as I can display the row number to the screen.

Here is IF / ELSE my code:

```
    if ($row_count === 0) {
        echo "<p>Be the first to enter a game comment and earn points toward your next fan badge.</p>";
    } else {
                   // no need to show code as this already works!
```

Comment: The if-else condition is outside the while loop, right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$row_count = 0;

I am adding to the count inside the while statement

```
     while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
     {
          // adding to count
          $row_count++;
       }
```

My count is working as I can display the row number to the screen.

Here is IF / ELSE  code:

```
    if ($row_count == 0) {
        echo "<p>Be the first to enter a game comment and earn points toward your next fan badge.</p>";
    } else {
                   // no need to show code as this already works!
             }
```

Answer (score 2):

you can use

```
mysql_num_rows($queryReference)
```

Hope this helps.
Thanks.

Comment: Doesn't seem to work.  Strange day for me.  Doesn't show anything in my else statement.

Comment: don't use it inside while, write it before while

Comment: I just created a second results query, and added another while statement.  Likely I made it more confusing but it works now.

Answer (score 1):

Please do one thing print this value using below function and tell me what is output

```
var_dump($row_count);
```

or you can use == instead of ===

Comment: Do you know where I should put this function in the code?  Thanks.

Comment: I just created a second results query, and added another while statement.  Likely I made it more confusing but it works now.

Answer (score 1):

```
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM comments");
$c = mysql_num_rows($query);
if($c==0) {
    echo "<p>Be the first to enter a game comment and earn points toward your next fan badge.</p>";
}
else {
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($query))
    {
        $vars = $row[index];
    }
}
```

Comment: I just created a second results query, and added another while statement.  Likely I made it more confusing but it works now.